# Auth / Capture using Adaptive Payment of Paypal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Is it possible to do authorization and capture using Adaptive Payment of Paypal ? How ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of, but it's not really the same.  What you would do is use the [Preapproval API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) to create a preapproval profile for the payer(s) using your app.  Then you can pass the preapproval key that you get back into future [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) calls to submit payments on their behalf without further approval.

Setting up the preapproval would be similar to authorization a payment, and then running the pay call to trigger a payment would be similar to capturing.

[This guide on setting up preapproval profiles](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/) should help you understand how it all works.

Answer (score 0):

Also please keep in mind:

> The preapproved maximum total amount of all payments cannot exceed
>   $2,000 USD or the equivalent in other currencies.