# PayPal authorization & capture and Adaptive Payment

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

Our app is a markeplace where buyers can make multi-vendor orders.
When the buyer completes a multi-vendor order its total amount in only authorized, then the multi-vendor order is splitted in n vendor sub-orders. 
When a single vendor sub-order is processed, by the vendor, its amount is captured by us and then we pay "manually" the seller due amount, holding our fee.
Actually we use PayPal authorization & capture between the buyer and us, then we pay "manually" the seller due amounts as described above.

We want to use the Adaptive Delayed Chained Payment to capture the single vendor sub-order amounts splitting they automatically between us and the seller.
Is that possible? How?

I see the following similar question:
[Auth / Capture using Adaptive Payment of Paypal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017708/auth-capture-using-adaptive-payment-of-paypal)
but is outdated and the links in the @Andrew Angell's response aren't available anymore.

Thanks

Comment: I updated the links in the answer for that other question.

Comment: I also added a new link to a guide on how the whole process works, and then the other links now point to the API references directly.  That should give you what you need to get it done.  If you're working with PHP you can use [this class library](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) to make those calls quick and easy.

Comment: Another question. Our app in based on Magento & WebKul Marketplace module (https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Extensions/Marketplace/Magento-Marketplace.html). We want to use the chained delayed payment but the WenBul support wrote us: "Now PayPal Acceptable Use policy does not support Adaptive PayPal Payment for Chained Payment type". Is that possible?

Comment: They quotes https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/ua/acceptableuse-full section 3-e

Comment: I have not had any problems getting delayed chained payment apps approved.  That's exactly what they made it available for.

Comment: I agree with you, but their claim gets me confused. The full story is here: https://webkul.com/ticket/tickets.php?id=20999. Thanks any way!